# How to Dock to StatusBar

Tags: vb.net

I have Form with StatusBar on it. On StatusBar there are ToolStripStatusLabel1 and ToolStripProgressBar1. Normaly, ToolStripProgressBar is not visible.
But when I start file copying ToolStripStatusLabel1 becames invisible and ToolStripProgressBar becames visible.

like this:

```
ToolStripStatusLabel1.Visible = False
ToolStripProgressBar1.Visible = True
```

Problem is that in this condition I cant get that ProgressBar take all the space of StatusBar not with increasing it's width nor with setting it's Dock property to .Fill.

```
ToolStripStatusLabel1.Visible = False
ToolStripStatusLabel1.Width = 0
ToolStripProgressBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

Is it possible to get ToolStripProgressBar1 to take full Width of StatusBar in described situation?

Comment: just because you make the label invisible doesnt mean it no longer has any width.  See if setting the width to 0 works.

Comment: I try that, don't work.

Comment: It probably has an `AutoSize` set to true and will not let it go to 0

Comment: Also, with removing AutoSize I didn't get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ToolStripProgressBar is quite limited and can't do what you want.

An alternative is to make a **regular** ProgressBar take the place of your entire StatusStrip:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private PB As New ProgressBar
    Private ShowProgress As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ShowProgressBar(True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ShowProgressBar(False)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowProgressBar(ByVal Visible As Boolean)
        ShowProgress = Visible
        If ShowProgress Then
            Dim rc As Rectangle = StatusStrip1.RectangleToScreen(StatusStrip1.ClientRectangle)
            PB.Bounds = Me.RectangleToClient(rc)
            PB.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right Or AnchorStyles.Bottom
            Me.Controls.Add(PB)
            PB.BringToFront()
        Else
            Me.Controls.Remove(PB)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Idle, not most elegant but suit my needs perfectly. Do you have any trick to show real value of PB except value -1 on windows 7?

Comment: Mare sure you've set appropriate Min/Max values.  I'm not aware of any issues with the ProgressBar on Win 7.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: As I can see program runs faster than ProgressBar what cuses that slider never commes to end like was on windows XP. To get real value showed I have to do .Value -=1. But that is also not 100% right.